# How to deal with multi-page react application with django?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

Has anyone built a multi page react app using ReactJS, Django and Django-REST. I have a good idea on how to achieve it. But the problem i want to build a multi html page app with ReactJS. There will be some endpoints which deliver HTML and others which deliver API data. For delivering HTML, i will use Django templates and for API data i will use DJango-REST. I can make a GET request for an HTML page from a react component with Axios, but the problem is i will need a way to render this HTML response from the frontend. My plan is to rewrite the DOM using document.write(ReturnedHTML). Will there be any potential performance problems with this approach? The returned HTML file will be extremely simple with the only difference being the  React files being imported.

Have not started yet. Asking for design approaches.